# How can I get the data-id in an appended button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**JavaScript**

```js
$("#btn").on('click', function(){
    $("#result").append("<button type='button' id='btnid'
    data-id='show' //this is what I want to get
    class='close pull-right' aria-hidden='true'>some text here</button>");
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<button id="btn">CLICK HERE</button>
<div id='result'></div>
<button id="submit">SUBMIT HERE</button>
```

I want to display the `data-id='show'` from the appended button after i click the button with an `id="submit"`. As you can see, the div with `id="result"` is just like an container of all the appended text.

So far, this is what I have,

**JavaScript**

```js
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $( "#result" ).each(function( index ) {
        console.log( index + ": " +$(this).text());
    });
});
```

But with this code, i can only retrieve the text, "some text here". But what i needed is the data-id of my appended button.

I also tried the code below, but it is not working.

**JavaScript**

```js
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $( "#result" ).each(function( index ) {
        console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).html($(this).html($(this).attr("data-id"))));
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you have `$( "#result" ).each(function( index ) {` ? Are you aware that you can't have more than one element with id `result` ?

Comment: tottlay accepted @dystroy

Comment: not so sure sir.. My friend only advice me to use each to get all the data, or id in a certain div. I'm not really sure with my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user clicks the `#btn` "CLICK HERE" button more than once you will end up with multiple new buttons appended within `#result` (which would be invalid html given that you'd then have duplicate `id` values), so you'd need to loop through those buttons with `.each()` rather than trying to loop through `#result` with `.each()`:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $("#result").find("button").each(function(index ) {
      console.log( index + ": " + $(this).attr("data-id"));
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NXU9e/

NOTE: The markup for your `#result` element is missing the `/` in the closing `</div>` tag.

Comment: ohh. thanks.. let me try it first.. and i have already edited the #result closing div

Answer (score 2):

To get the data-id of the buttons you have in the `#result` element, you may do this :

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $('#result button').each(function(i){
         console.log(i, ':', $(this).data('id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
  console.log($("#result").find("button").data('id'));
});
```

make sure you id is unique.... each with ids does not make sense

Comment: make sure you click btn  first else the result will not have button and will be undefined... else you need to chnage your logic